# Section gets included in header

Tags: header-footer

I wrote a header for my notes in class.For the header i just wanted "My notes" in the center.So i used "My notes" in the \chead.After quick build i get the name of a section on every page included in the header.

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \chead{My Notes\\}
 \rfoot{\thepage}
```

So it should show just "My Notes" but instead it shows "My Notes" and "Section 2" in the header.I am currently using Texmaker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *clear* all headers (and/or footers) before setting them, otherwise regular header/footer content may still make their way into your display. [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) provides this clearing mechanism via `\fancyhf{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\chead{My Notes}% \fancyhead[C]{...}
\rfoot{\thepage}% \fancyfoot[R]{...}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```